# SSR hydration error when using hook with useState (Next.js v.12)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hydration

App and path are (determined by the url from ctx) and are passed down as props from getServerSideProps to the component.

```
// Hook

export default function usePath(app, path) {
  const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const config = globalConfig[app]

    if (config) {
      const { paths } = globalConfig

      const isMatching = paths.find(({ pattern }) => pattern.test(path))

      if (isMatching) {
        setCurrentPath(isMatching.path)
      }
    }
  }, [app, path])

  return currentPath
}
```

Component utilizing the hook:

```
const currentPath = usePath(app, path)

// Hydration error here:
<p>{app && currentPath ? t(`sentence.${currentPath}`) : t(`sentence.defaultMessage`)}</p>

/* 
Server renders: sentence.defaultMessage, 
while the client renders: sentence.${currentPath}. 
*/
```

Why do I get a hydration miss match in this case?

If I omit useState and the useEffect, and just handle this without these hooks it works (storing in a let var instead). But I'm interested in the underlying issue.

Works:

```
export default function useChainPath(app, path) {
  const config = globalConfig[app]
  let currentPath = ''


  if (config) {
    const { paths } = config

    const isMatching = paths.find(({ pattern }) => pattern.test(path))

    if (isMatching) {
      currentPath = isMatching.path
    }
  }

  return currentPath
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`useEffect` doesn't run on the server, as it only runs after markup has rendered to the dom.
So when `usePath` runs on the server the value of `currentPath` never gets set, and always stays undefined. Only when it gets to the client, after initial render useEffect runs.

To overcome this please consider using `useMemo` instead of `useEffect`+`useState`.

```js
export default function usePath(app, path) {
  const currentPath = useMemo(()=>{
    const config = globalConfig[app]

    if (config) {
      const { paths } = globalConfig

      return paths.find(({ pattern }) => pattern.test(path))

    }
  }, [app, path])

  return currentPath
}
```